# How Spread Text in a Python Listbox Display From a Mysql Query

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

My code is working, I just want it to appear easier on the eyes.

```
2-12312 Bob Seesaw Active

4-1212 Jim Beene Off
```

I would like spread it out to make it easier to read (SORRY USING DOTS FOR SPACES)

```
2-12312......Bob Seesaw.....Active

4-1212.......Jim Beene........ Off
```

I put in the code specific

```
from tkinter import *
import pymysql as mdb

from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Listbox

-------
 def viewroster():
    rosterList.delete(0, "end")
    dbi = mdb.connect("localhost", port=3306, user="user", passwd="pass", db="interactive_db")
    cursor = dbi.cursor()
   cursor.execute("""SELECT number, firstname, surname, available FROM active_roster""")
   rows=cursor.fetchall()
   dbi.close()
print (rows)
for results in rows:
  rosterList.insert("end", results)

rosterList=Listbox(root, height=6,width=65)
rosterList.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=9, columnspan=4)

showButt=Button(root, text="Show All", width=12, command=viewroster)
showButt.grid(row=13, column=3)
```

.

```
2-12312 Bob Seesaw Active

4-1212 Jim Beene Off
```

I would like spread it out to make it easier to read(SORRY USING DOTS FOR SPACES)

```
2-12312.....Bob Seesaw....Active

4-1212......Jim Beene ....Off
```

I am getting no errors

Comment: use button `{}` to format examples and to correctly format code.

Comment: use monospaced font to correctly format text  in `Listbox`

Comment: use string formatting to get correct number of spaces between columns - [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string formatting

```
print( "| {:15s} | {:15s} | {:15s} |".format('2-12312', 'Bob', 'Seesaw Active') )
print( "| {:15s} | {:15s} | {:15s} |".format('4-1212', 'Jim', 'Beene Off') )
```

to get

```
| 2-12312         | Bob             | Seesaw Active   |
| 4-1212          | Jim             | Beene Off       |
```

See page [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

But you will have to use `monspaced` font to correctly display it in `Listbox`.

Wikipedia: [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)